# OWASP ZAP Scan for Salesforce Security Scan

Tags: salesforce, zap

I am a salesforce developer and need to go through a salesforce security review they need OWASP ZAP report for my app because I have used the stripe API for payment

Endpoint: https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_methods

Now here I cant used chimera as I don't own the endpoint.

Anyone knows how to create a ZAP report for salesforce with endpoint like this.

I got the following link as help but its no good for me.

https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/webapp/zaprunningscan

Thanks

Comment: "I got the following link as help but its no good for me." please be more specific.

Comment: I went to the link which is given by salesforce support but in that video, there is no explanation of test Rest API via ZAP

Comment: I am able to create an OpenAPI Rest file but not able to Scan in ZAP?

Comment: Did you install the OpenAPI add-on and import it?

Comment: Yes I do import and I got message that your api successfully parse but after that nothing happened no movement in terminal

Comment: @ParthNaik did you pass security review? How did you generate the report for the endpoint?